# Restringing Acoustic guitar

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings

I always have issues restringing the high E string. It breaks when tuning it. So today I used 2nd string as the first one and tuned it to High E, does it have a significant impact on tonality?

Comment: Does it tend to break at the same point and if so, where? There may be a sharp edge it can't cope with.

Comment: Maybe the obvious question… are you absolutely certain you're tuning it to the correct note?

Comment: I agree with @Tim, a sharp edge on the saddle or nut might be the culprit. Does it always break in the same place?

Comment: Yes, please consider what @Tim said. Skipping the first string is a hack that surely won’t be sustainable. Instead try to fix the problem. If the string consistently breaks there is probably something wrong with either the bridge, the nut or the tuning pegs. Such edges can easily be smoothened out. So by looking at where the string breaks you can determine where the problem lies.

Comment: I had that issue with a different string after I had a new bone saddle installed on one of my acoustic guitars.  Turns out the saddle had a sharp edge that I had to file down with a a very fine material (did not take much).  I read about and tried applying graphite in the little groves your strings cut in the saddle.  Just use a number two pencil and rub it in the groove.  That lubricates the point of contact to reduce friction when tightening the string to bring it to pitch.

Answer (score 2):

The tonality is easily checked by comaring the 12th fret harmonic with the pitch it produces when 12th fret is fretted.

It *may* put that string a little out of tune as you go up the neck, but a bigger problem I see is that the string is much tighter than the others in the set. Making it feel strange to fret. It's not the real answer to your problem. The extra tension is hardly going to do much else apart from increase its propensity to break due to increased tension, but if it breaks at the same point as the others, there will probably be a sharp causing it. Maybe at the saddle, maybe the nut or even the machine head winding post itself. You may have solved the sympton but not the cause.

What gauge strings (individually) are on now?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. Intonation is balance of factors, and going from .012 to .016 for the high E (gauges from Stringjoy's light set) might mean the bridge is in the wrong place and your higher strings will be off.

My concern is that the tension would be much higher — moving from 25 to 45 lbs of tension — so assuming it would not break, it would be uncomfortable to play. As a desperate stopgap measure, you can do it but I wouldn't want to leave it that way. Not because you'll break your guitar (maybe you will?) but because it will hurt your fingers.

Seriously, new musicians who start on guitar do not have trained ears, which means that you do not know what the high E should be. I certainly did not, and once bought a ten-pack of replacement E strings because I was breaking so many. (Guitar store guy thought I was making a tattoo gun.) Electronic tuners help with this. Strings cost like a dollar each (in the US) and there are great free phone apps you can use. Learn to tune it right with the right strings.

This is assuming this is a steel-string acoustic guitar. I think it would be fine with a nylon-string guitar, but I'm not sure.